# Want to use YDN-db database instead of Ajax with Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, ydn-db

I want to use YDN-db with select2, i tried few options but unable to sort.

So i want to use executeSql command as below

```
APP.db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM products WHERE name like '%test%'").then(function(results) {
  //something
}
```

so i tried following in last (i already used other tweaks of it aswell)

```
$('#add_product_id').select2({
                        data:function (params) {
                             console.log(params);   
                            APP.db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM products WHERE name = '"+params+"'").then(function(resultRows) {                           
                            if(resultRows.length > 0) {
                                $.each( resultRows, function( i, productRow ) {
                                    console.log(productRow);
                                        var title ='<span class="result-title">' + productRow.name + '</span>';
                                        var price = '<span class="result-price">' + productRow.price + '</span>'
                                        ;
                                        var sku = '<span class="result-sku">' + pos_i18n[60] + ' ' + productRow.sku + '</span>';
                                        var stock = '<span class="result-stock">' + pos_i18n[61] + ' ' + productRow.stock_quantity + '</span>';

                                        var firstRow =  '<div class="result-row first">' + title + price + '</div>';
                                        var secondRow = '<div class="result-row second">' + sku + stock + '</div>';
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
                            return markup;
                        },
                        minimumInputLength: 3,
                        cache: true,
                        multiple: true,
                    }).change(function () {
                        var val = $(this).select2('data');
                        $(this).html('');
                        if (!empty(val)) {
                            val = is_array(val) ? val[0] : val;

                            }
                    });
```

YDN query executed by requested parameter not coming log which user actually types on search2 field,

> console.log(params);

Please can any one guide me **how can i use YDN-db instead of Ajax with Select2**?

Comment: do any one know about this??

Comment: This looks like the option you need: https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#alternative-transport-methods

Comment: @freedomn-m thank you let me have a look and try, will update you after try.

Comment: @freedomn-m can you please share one small example how it can be as i am unable to get how can i write over here, i mean i should pass in the AjaxRequest or in the paramURL?

Comment: Don't know anything about [tag:ydn-db], sorry.

Comment: @freedomn-m thank you, then in this case can you guide me instead of ajax, how can i just use local array/object pass fpr select2 options?

Comment: @freedomn-m can you help me sir in this?

Comment: Did you review: https://select2.org/data-sources/arrays  You may need to reformat your data into the required format.

Comment: So nice of you sir, that is really helpful and what exactly is required. Let me convert data accordingly and pass